# How to use JavaFX SimpleSwingBrowser in Processing IDE?

Tags: javafx, processing

I had just found this website: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm.
On this site, there is an example to create a SimpleSwingBrowser.
The problem is that I can't use this code in Processing and I don't know how I can edit it so it will work.

Is there a way to use the JavaFX SimpleSwingBrowser in Processing (If needed in a Swing Frame or something like that)?

Thanks in advance,
Daantje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to import JavaFX code into Processing, which seems weird because Processing supports using JavaFX as a renderer. It might be possible to import JavaFX code, but a quick Google doesn't reveal how.

But hope is not lost. You can also just use Processing as a Java library, and run your sketch that way instead of via the Processing editor. [Here](https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) is a tutorial that should get you started with that.

Then when you have your sketch running via Java, you can create a JavaFX frame however you normally would.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe a stupid question, but which one (https://eclipse.org/downloads/) is the 'standard' version of Eclipse which is right for me? (I haven't used Eclipse before)

Comment: @DoTog Well, note that you don't have to use eclipse. You can use whatever you were using to program in JavaFX before.

Comment: @DoTog but Eclipse Neon is the latest version, so I'd go with that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have now downloaded Eclipse Neon, created a project and added the core.jar file of Processing into that project. I will let you know when everything works :-)

Comment: @DoTog No problem. Good luck!